# $request->session didn't work in Laravel 5.3 resource controller

Tags: php, laravel, oop, session, laravel-5.3

First of all, I already check that in other controller (not in resource controller) my session work very well, but when I did it in the resource controller my code for get session didn't work.

Here's my resource controller

```
  <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

//tambahan
use DB;
use Session;

//model
use App\_admins;
use App\Mahasiswas;

class MahasiswaController extends Controller
{
    protected $data;
    protected $token;

    public function __contruct(){
        $this->data = array();
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->token = $request->session()->get('_admin_id');
            if (!$request->session()->has('_admin_id')) {
                abort(404);
            }
            return $next($request);
        });
    }

    private function user($token){
        $this->data['query'] = _admins::find($token);
    }

    public function index(){
        echo $this->token;
    }
```

There is more public function, but it's still empty so I am not showing it here to avoid confusion. And here is my route in web.php:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin'],function(){

    Route::resource('/admin/mahasiswa','MahasiswaController');
    Route::resource('/admin/nilai','NilaiController');

});
```

Comment: Any errors produced? You're calling `$request` in your constructor, but I don't see it as a parameter? Try type hinting like: `__construct(Request $request)`.

Comment: @camelCase okay i add that, but its still same, i still dont get any data from my session, this code work perfectly in other controller (not resource controller)

Comment: Is it returning `null` if you `dd($request->session)` in your `constructor`?

Comment: yes, its still returning 'null'

Comment: i believe i code well, cause it's not shown syntax error, but why i didn't get my session? resource controller like just forgetting my session

Comment: You know what, I'm recalling that this is normal because the session middleware hasn't run yet in the constructor. I bet you're able to access the session outside the constructor, right?

Comment: Yes, you right, wow great. Now how to fix it, i just want to call it from my controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `5.3` the middleware hasn't run yet in the `constructor`, so you're unable to gather `session` data. But using your closure-based approach, you should be able to access it with something like this:

```
$this->middleware(function($request, $next) {
    // Get the session value (uses global helper)
    $this->token = session('_admin_id');

    // If the value is null, abort the request
    if (null === $this->token) abort(404);

    return $next($request);
});
```