# laravel 5.4 : cant access Auth::user() in the __construct method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

In previous versions of Laravel, in the controllers which I needed to access logged user in all the methods  I used to do something like this:

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    private $user ;
    function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->user = \Auth::user();
    }

    function func_1(){
      $objects = Objects::where('user_id' , $this->user->id )->get();
    }
    function func_2(){
      $objects = Objects::where('user_id' , $this->user->id )->get();
    }
    function func_3(){
      $objects = Objects::where('user_id' , $this->user->id )->get();
    }
```

Mostly because I don't like the default syntax `\Auth::user()` but after upgrading to 5.4 this doesn't work anymore and I get `null` from `$this->user`

It works fine in other methods though. Basically `\Auth::user()` return `null` in the `__construct` method but works fine in the other functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$request->session didn't work in Laravel 5.3 resource controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40363009/request-session-didnt-work-in-laravel-5-3-resource-controller)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors) says :

> In previous versions of Laravel, you could access session variables or
>   the authenticated user in your controller's constructor. This was
>   never intended to be an explicit feature of the framework. In Laravel
>   5.3, you can't access the session or authenticated user in your controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet.

So try this :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user = Auth::user();

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Have To define Auth method before you load your class as you use your namespace.See the example below:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Auth;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    private $user ;
    function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->user = Auth::user();
    }

    function func_1(){
      $objects = Objects::where('user_id' , $this->user->id )->get();
    }
    function func_2(){
      $objects = Objects::where('user_id' , $this->user->id )->get();
    }
    function func_3(){
      $objects = Objects::where('user_id' , $this->user->id )->get();
    }
```

And After you can clean your cache if required.
php artisan config:cache