# Auth::user() Return Null 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am trying to make a package for Laravel.

I'm getting an issue when i use `Auth::user()` in controller in package folder it won't return the currently logged in user, it will only return `null`

When I put `Auth::user()` in a controller at `App\Http\Controllers` I do receive the currently logged in user.

[image]

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: You try to get it in the controller construct ?

Comment: Yes 'public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['admin', 'auth']);
    }'

Comment: What route hits the controller function you're printing Auth::user() on, is it namespaced correctly? Are you including your `Use` case for Auth Facade at the top of your file, this is difficult to give you an answer without you posting your routes that hit this admin file and the admin controller itself. Please update your question with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it like this :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['admin', 'auth']);
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user = Auth::user();

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

For more infos see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055775/4881811)

Comment: Nope Still Same return null

Comment: are you authenticated ?

Comment: yes i am pretty sure i am authenticated because when i use in HomeController.php try Auth::user() returning me full details of current user
but when i trying to use another folder like package/admin/src/http/controllers/AdminController.php it won't work maybe session not continue in this file

Comment: What about the import is it like this `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` ?

Comment: already Added use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; and use Auth; both tried

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177081/discussion-between-maraboc-and-sid-heart).

Comment: did this problem solved or not? I am facing the same. I am trying to make package and use Auth::user() inside it but shows null value.