# In laravel Controller Contructor calling a function and accessing the session is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I am using laravel 9.
In laravel I have created a Controller that has constructor in that I have included a custom class file from that file I am calling that function in constructor. In that function I am accessing the Session values which is always come as NULL.

```
use App\Common\{JwtTokenChecker};
class AbcController extends Controller
{
   public function __construct()
   {
     $this->jwt_token = new JwtTokenChecker();
     $this->jwt_token->checkExpiryTimeToGenerateToken();
   }
}
```

The class function:

```
public function checkExpiryTimeToGenerateToken()
{

    $check_before_token_expire = env('CHECK_TOKEN_EXPIRE_BEFORE_TIME');
    $session = app('session'); // or app('Illuminate\Session\Store') or 
    resolve('Illuminate\Session\Store')
    $ses_token = $session->get('jwt_token');
    $ses_expire = $session->get('jwt_token_expire_in');
    $currentTime = now()->timestamp;
    $currentTimeExpire = now()->timestamp + $ses_expire - $check_before_token_expire;
    //dd($ses_token, $ses_expire, $currentTime, $currentTimeExpire);

    if($currentTimeExpire <= $currentTime)
    {
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . session()->get('jwt_token');
        $result = $this->curlObject->callCurlMethod('GET','refresh', null, $headers);
        if(!empty($result))
        {
            $result = json_decode($result);
            //dd($result);
            if(isset($result->access_token))
            {
                $session->put('jwt_token', $result->access_token);
                $session->put('jwt_token_expire_in', $result->expires_in);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ERROR => Session as null

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233343/laravel-session-returns-null

Comment: The session hasn't been started when the `__construct()` method loads. There are several links that explain why and how to get around it like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542802/laravel-cant-get-session-in-controller-constructor/55887660 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62387697/laravel-7-user-data-in-construct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers are instantiated by the framework before a request is handled, so there is no session or authenticated user to access.

If you’re trying to authorised a JWT being passed in the request, then you should be doing this in middleware; not in a controller’s constructor.